# How to perform online data backup in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Recently i deleted an entire project in eclipse, but thankfully it was not totally deleted from the system and i was able to recover it . Now i wanted to know how can i backup data in eclipse. If i delete an android project by mistake, i should be able to recover it.
 Which kind of back up is better online backup of backup onto a hard disk? Is our data safe online. Please suggest me the following:

1) how can i backup my data using some software onto the hard disk.

2) Also, i want to know which is the best software to backup our data online. I would like if its free, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use a source code control system in-house or one of the [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465/easy-simple-online-source-control) online SCC services out there on the interwebs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of backing up the the workspace directly (which is perfectly possible using any standard backup tool) you could put your projects into a source code revision control system like subversion/cvs/git/mercurial/.... and back up this one instead. this has many advantages over working with a lokal workspace only (easy comparison of individual files, modification history etc)

Comment: @Tejas, you should really consider his idea because that is how my project managed by scm. Then backup the entire repository (which include the eclipse project setting) which is much safer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check out recommended online backup solutions at

http://www.backupreview.info